# SSIS: Export to file to include data definition

Tags: ssis

Any way to do this since we defined our fixed width within SSIS, any chance it can spit it out somewhere?  I have a project with like 20 different fixed width flat file exports.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what format you're looking for here, but off the top of my head, you could look into the XML of the package itself to see the column definitions of each Flat File.  The tag is something like .